# how can I calculate two times between two fixed times?

Tags: php

I want to calculate the hours in the attendance sheet
but I don't want to calculate the hours and minutes that are not between these two times that are: 08:00 to 14:00

for example:
employee A arrived to work at 09:00 and left at 16:00
the result should be 5 hours
and if Employee B arrived to work at 8:30 and left at 14:00
the result should be 5hours and 30 mins

kind regards

Comment: Show some effort. Some code u already wrote

Comment: `min(14:00, EmployeeAleaves) - max(08:00, EmployeeAarrives)`

Comment: echo $onclock2='08:00';
  echo $clockout2='14:05';
//echo ', ';
  //echo $onclick=$row['tbl_clockout'];
  //echo $clockout=$row['tbl_clockout'];
echo ' | Result: ';
$onclock1 = strtotime($onclock2);
$clockout1 = strtotime($clockout2);
echo $diff = abs($onclock1 - $clockout1) / 3600;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your answer

```
<?php
$restriction_start = strtotime("30-Mar-2015 08:00:00");
$restriction_end = strtotime("30-Mar-2015 14:00:00");

$start_time = strtotime("30-Mar-2015 09:00:00");
$end_time = strtotime("30-Mar-2015 16:00:00");


echo calculateTime($start_time, $end_time, $restriction_start, $restriction_end);


function calculateTime($start_time, $end_time, $restriction_start, $restriction_end)
{
    $start = $restriction_start;
    if($start_time>$restriction_start)
    {
        $start = $start_time;
    }

    $end = $restriction_end;
    if($end_time<$restriction_end)
    {
        $end = $end_time;
    }

    $time_diff = $end-$start;

    $output = gmdate("H:i:s", $time_diff);

    return $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datetime object to do that. There is the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $NbrSec = mktime($hour1, $minute1, $second1, $month1, $day1, $year1)
               - mktime($hour2, $minute2, $second2, $month2, $day2, $year2);

var $Hr = ((int)($NbrSec / 60)) * 60;
var $Mn = $NbrSec % 60;

echo $Hr . ":" . $Mn;
```

Comment: it would be more effective answer if you provide description your code